# Are there freely available equivalents to the HUD crosswalk data (zip code to county/census mapping) that go back farther in time?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

The US Department of Housing and Urban Development provides [crosswalk data sets that map zip codes to Census tracts, counties, etc. and vice versa](http://www.huduser.org/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html). Unfortunately these data only go back to 2010, and use different definitions (2000 Census vs 2010 Census) after a certain point, so I may have to convert these Census divisions anyway (as [this question talks about](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1412/3565)).

Are there any freely available datasets that contain zip code to census tract and/or county mappings (or vice versa) going back farther than 2010? I've read of proprietary datasets that do this in journal articles, but I haven't found anything open and free.

Comment: I looked around t see if somebody had archived the 2000 version of the file before HUD stopped making it available. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although zctas and zip codes are not perfect equivalents, they are pretty close.

you can generate any conceivable crosswalk with census 2010, 2000, or 1990 geographies here:

http://mcdc.missouri.edu/websas/geocorr12.html

http://mcdc.missouri.edu/websas/geocorr2k.html

http://mcdc.missouri.edu/websas/geocorr90.shtml

Comment: It looks like these crosswalks use USPS zip codes (postal zip codes), which is what I need, not zip code tabulation areas, so this is perfect! Now I just need it for all the years in between...

Comment: Are you sure this is USPS zip codes and not ZCTAs in the mcdc? I'm pretty sure it's ZCTAs...

Comment: mcdc has zctas not zip codes  http://mcdc.missouri.edu/websas/maggot12.shtml#zip